# How to specify first-day-of-week for PrimeVue Calendar?

Tags: vue.js, calendar, primevue

Is there a way to specify first-day-of-week for PrimeVue Calendar? The best solution would be, if i could set it globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing first day of the week globally you should go to main.ts and set firstDayOfWeek: 1 for locale by the createApp(App) const. Not forget change the dayNames, dayNamesShort, dayNamesMin for your language too! You can find a list from all the options [here](https://primevue.org/configuration/#locale)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change only `firstDayOfWeek` and do not need to override other settings then you can use default ones:

```
/// mait.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import PrimeVue, { defaultOptions } from 'primevue/config';
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(PrimeVue, {
    // your configuration
    locale: {
        ...defaultOptions.locale, // use default values for everything else
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,        // change to Monday
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to only change the firstDayOfWeek ? When I do so I get errors since I didn't change the other locale settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).